# How to create Model to read data from MS Access database?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm very new to MVVM.

Question is:

I have a Access database with 2 simple tables - `owner, dvd`.
How to structure Model in MVVM pattern (and ideally ViewModel too)?
All I need in this tutorial is to be able to display it in some datagrid. (I presume View should not impact how we build model and viewmodel).

I was not able to find any tutorial about it. Any link would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but if you really search you will find a lot of suitable tutorials for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- TypedDataSet (class for each Table with columns as properties, and Adapters for fiil\update data). easy with VS wizard (Data > Add Data Source...).
- Create owner & dvd class, and a Data Layer which returns lists (of owner and dvd) with OleDbDataReader's.